# Not able to remove the Dart not a valid package name error

Tags: android, flutter

[Dart not a valid package name error click here to see the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8M5j.png)

I can't seem to understand what is the issue here as new is the folder where I am trying to save the new flutter project I am creating but I am getting the error new is not a valid dart package name how to remove this error. I have tried everything I cant find anything on other places and questions.

Answer (score 0):

you are very likely naming your project as "`new project`"; project name can't can't contain spaces and it will be treated like you named your project as "`new`" which is a keyword in dart. So, name the project without spaces like `new_project`

Comment: Actually I am naming the project as you had suggested, but not working for me. It is taking the name of folder which I am using as the Project location and giving the error.

Comment: try creating a new project in a different folder and make sure there is no space in the path of the project.